# segmentation fault ERROR

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node

I just started in learning substrate and I want to run the example. I take the tutorial on the site https://docs.substrate.io/install/macos/.
I have already done all steps. I tried run test blockchain by command `./target/release/node-template --dev`

Unfortunately, I got the problem `zsh: segmentation fault  ./target/release/node-template --dev`.

I was searching the problem in the Internet, but it was without result. But if I enter the command without argument "--dev", it works without errors, but finalized blocks not generated (always get this output from terminal: `2023-10-18 10:12:00  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x6629…5b92), finalized #0 (0x6629…5b92), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0` ).

I tried to solve the problem: 1) by increasing space in node js; 2) by downgrading nigthly
It was unsuccessfull :(

If I run code with command `RUST_BACKTRACE=1 ./target/release/node-template -ldebug --dev` I get this output: `main wasm_overrides: Neither WASM override nor substitute available for block 0x9d35…79e5, using onchain code`

I'm using macOS Sonoma 14.0.

I will be grateful for the answers you provide!

Comment: I encountered the same problem. My Mac os is also 14.0 (23A344). I feel that it is a problem with macos, but I don’t know where to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Did you overclock your PC?

Comment: Any udpate ? I am facing the same issue on my mac.